# Why are collisions and contacts both detectable in Swift (Xcode)?

Tags: ios, swift

Why are collisions and contacts both detectable in Swift? Isn't a collision a subset of a contact? In other words, by monitoring contacts, aren't you also monitoring collisions?

Answer (score 1):

A collision and contact are two different things.
**A collision is used when you need to decide if your body should strike another body and react to the strike or ignore it.**
 In collision detection, when two objects come into contact with each other, the physics is simulated and the direction of movement of the one or both of the objects may change depending on their properties(like mass and whether the object is dynamic). The two objects do not share the same space at the same time.

**Contact detection is used to detect whether two objects are touching each other.** The two objects can pass through each other (if collision detection is not enabled). When they intersect contact is begun. The contact is ended when they no longer intersect.

For example, take the classic [Breakout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakout_(video_game)) game.
In this game we need the detect collision between the ball and the brick and the ball and the paddle. In this case we use collision detection. This makes the ball strike and react to the paddle and the bricks. We also need contact detection to keep track of which brick the ball has hit.

Consider another game in which the character needs to collect a power-up place at a particular point in the screen. In this case, you don't need to simulate the collision between the power-up and the character. The power-up is usually collected when the character passes through it. This cannot happen if collision detection is enabled. The character only needs to detect contact with the power-up. This is where you use contact detection.

Comment: That makes sense, but wouldn't monitoring contact also suffice for monitoring collisions?

Comment: like i said monitoring contact doesn't enable monitoring collisions. since we need to detect them separately. just like in my two examples.